# How to reset a FON SIMPL wireless router

Tags: router, wireless-networking, reset

I have a FON SIMPL Wireless router, and I need to reset it to factory default settings.

The problem is, there simply isn't a reset button or hole I can insert a paperclip in to.

Can't find anything on the internet about this router in terms of support, just articles about it:

[FON SIMPL](http://english.martinvarsavsky.net/general/fon-to-unveil-new-fonera-at-mobile-world-congress.html)

Their other routers all have either a separate reset button, or it's the WPS / Reset button.

This router only has a WPS button, which I pushed and held for at least a minute to no avail.

Does anyone have experience with this router?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

for anyone googling this, here's the solution:
http://wiki.fon.com/wiki/Restore_Factory_Settings